# Beginning Git version control

Tags: git, version-control

Could anyone please recommend any good books to learn to use the Git version control system as a beginner?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion for when you are learning... Git may seem complicated, but it is actually one of the most simple SCM's in existence.  Under the hood, you typically only deal with three types of objects: blob, tree, commit.  A blob stores file data.  A tree stores a list of references to blobs and trees (making a dir tree).  A commit records the state of the repo at a given point in time, along with the previous state (eg, parent commits). Everything that you learn will be easier to understand if you grasp how brilliantly simple the git repository is... Then manipulating it becomes very easy.

Comment: Closed for wrong reason, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258839/best-git-book-for-a-noob, exact duplicate. It is constructive.

Comment: @gahooa Thanks very much for that. I've used Mercurial a bit but now I'm moving to Git it seems quite different but hopefully get the hang of it once I get using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- http://book.git-scm.com/
- http://progit.org/

And probably any mentioned in these questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347454/suggest-a-book-to-learn-git
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258839/best-git-book-for-a-noob

And of course, don't forget to search SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+book

Comment: That's great thank you. Sorry I did do a quick search but nothing came up immediately so probably should have looked further!

Comment: You can also check this http://sencibles.com/getting-started-with-git/